# Django .raw query fails (error 1064) -- but works in SQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-1.11

(using django 1.11.2, python 2.7.10, mysql 5.7.18)

The following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    transaction_transaction.id,
    sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(extract(HOUR_SECOND from transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime))))
    AS average_time_of_day
FROM transaction_transaction
INNER JOIN store_store ON (transaction_transaction.store_id=store_store.id)
INNER JOIN payment_method_card ON (transaction_transaction.card_id=payment_method_card.id)
WHERE (
    transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime BETWEEN '2017-08-31 00:00:00' AND '2017-08-31 23:59:59'
    AND store_store.company_id=2
    AND payment_method_card.profile_id=8
);
```

Runs and returns the following result (as expected):

```
+== id ==+== average_time_of_day ==+
|= 9422 =|===== 20:42:22.8695 =====|
```

(This is run from HeidiSQL)

Doing something similar (I think! but something is obviously wrong) via Django:

```
average_time_of_day = Transaction.objects.raw(
    '''
    SELECT 
        transaction_transaction.id, 
        sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(extract(HOUR_SECOND from transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime)))) 
        AS average_time_of_day
    FROM transaction_transaction
    INNER JOIN store_store ON (transaction_transaction.store_id=store_store.id) 
    %s
    WHERE (
        transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime BETWEEN %s AND %s 
        AND store_store.company_id=%s
        %s
    );
    ''',
    [
        'INNER JOIN payment_method_card ON (transaction_transaction.card_id=payment_method_card.id) ' if profile_pk else '',
        start_datetime,
        end_datetime,
        company_pk,
        'AND payment_method_card.profile_id=' + str(profile_pk) if profile_pk else '',
    ]
)
```

Doing

```
print average_time_of_day.query
```

Outputs:

```
SELECT
    transaction_transaction.id,
    sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(extract(HOUR_SECOND from transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime))))
    AS average_time_of_day
FROM transaction_transaction
INNER JOIN store_store ON (transaction_transaction.store_id=store_store.id)
INNER JOIN payment_method_card ON (transaction_transaction.card_id=payment_method_card.id)
WHERE (
    transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime BETWEEN 2017-08-31 00:00:00 AND 2017-08-31 00:00:00
    AND store_store.company_id=2
    AND payment_method_card.profile_id=8
);
```

And Django returns with the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''INNER JOIN payment_method_card ON (transaction_transaction.card_id=payment_meth' at line 7")
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: mmmm: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#extract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right.

This one will teach me not to try and:

1. be too clever
2. use one-liners too much :-(

This was not working:

```
average_time_of_day = Transaction.objects.raw(
    '''
    SELECT 
        transaction_transaction.id, 
        sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(extract(HOUR_SECOND from transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime)))) 
        AS average_time_of_day
    FROM transaction_transaction
    INNER JOIN store_store ON (transaction_transaction.store_id=store_store.id) 
    %s
    WHERE (
        transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime BETWEEN %s AND %s 
        AND store_store.company_id=%s
        %s
    );
    ''',
    [
        'INNER JOIN payment_method_card ON (transaction_transaction.card_id=payment_method_card.id) ' if profile_pk else '',
        start_datetime,
        end_datetime,
        company_pk,
        'AND payment_method_card.profile_id=' + str(profile_pk) if profile_pk else ''
    ]
)
```

Notice the `'INNER JOIN payment_method_card ON (transaction_transaction.card_id=payment_method_card.id) ' if profile_pk else ''`  and `'AND payment_method_card.profile_id=' + str(profile_pk) if profile_pk else ''` in the `params` sent to the raw() method. Kind of dynamic?

... But **this** works:

```
if profile_pk:
    average_time_of_day = Transaction.objects.raw(
        '''
        SELECT
            transaction_transaction.id,
            sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(extract(HOUR_SECOND from transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime))))
            AS average_time_of_day
        FROM transaction_transaction
        INNER JOIN store_store ON (transaction_transaction.store_id=store_store.id)
        INNER JOIN payment_method_card ON (transaction_transaction.card_id=payment_method_card.id)
        WHERE (
            transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime BETWEEN %s AND %s
            AND store_store.company_id=%s
            AND payment_method_card.profile_id=%s
        );
        ''',
        [
            start_datetime,
            end_datetime,
            company_pk,
            profile_pk
        ]
    )
else:
    average_time_of_day = Transaction.objects.raw(
        '''
        SELECT
            transaction_transaction.id,
            sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(extract(HOUR_SECOND from transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime))))
            AS average_time_of_day
        FROM transaction_transaction
        INNER JOIN store_store ON (transaction_transaction.store_id=store_store.id)
        WHERE (
            transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime BETWEEN %s AND %s
            AND store_store.company_id=%s
        );
        ''',
        [
            start_datetime,
            end_datetime,
            company_pk
        ]
    )
```

So could Django not like at all the dynamic building of `params`? I'd be very glad to know the answer... I still suspect I did something wrong, though ... Could this have anything to do with SQL injection protection?

Apparently Django was wrapping the `INNER JOIN` expressions in single quotes - hence causing MySQL to reject the query. Which actually looked like this, even though `print average_time_of_day.query` was not saying anything about it:

```
SELECT
    transaction_transaction.id,
    sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(extract(HOUR_SECOND from transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime))))
    AS average_time_of_day
FROM transaction_transaction
INNER JOIN store_store ON (transaction_transaction.store_id=store_store.id)
'INNER JOIN payment_method_card ON (transaction_transaction.card_id=payment_method_card.id)'
WHERE (
    transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime BETWEEN 2017-08-31 00:00:00 AND 2017-08-31 23:59:59
    AND store_store.company_id=2
    'AND payment_method_card.profile_id=8'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL string some variable must be string. for example datetime must be in "" or '' i can't remember but `queryset.query` show you formated sql string not valid string.
So just try to add ''.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using Django's ORM to build that query? It could make debugging it a lot easier. It might look something like this:

```
Transaction.objects.filter(
    store__company_id=company_pk,
    payment_method_card__profile_id=profile_pk,
    transaction_datetime__range(start_datetime, end_datetime)
)
```

You can optimize the query using [Django's `select_related` and `prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) on your query, and you can use a [`Q() object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) if you need finer-grained control.

I've got no love for writing out SQL statements manually, so this is a bit of a cop-out, but I like using the tools that Django gives me.

Comment: Oh yes I have tried. Unfortunately, as far as I'm aware, django does not support the "sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(extract(HOUR_SECOND from transaction_transaction.transaction_datetime))))" bit.